# Searching for a value in a list with Prolog

Tags: list, recursion, prolog, member

I'm writing a recursive function in Prolog to check if a course (Crs) in a semester (SEM, a list) has its pre requisite course met in Prior (a list). there are 2 examples of Course in the second block of code. But when it runs it fails for csse1001 (which has no prerequisite), when it should return true as it has to search for nothing. What am I missing?

```
checkSem(Prior,[]). 
checkSem(Prior,SEM):-
    [Crs|Tail] = SEM,
    member(pre(Crs,List),Prior),
    checkSem(Prior,Tail).
```

Course:

```
partA(comp3506).
lvl3(comp3506).
s1(comp3506).
pre(comp3506,[csse2002]).

partA(csse1001).
lvl1(csse1001).
s1(csse1001).
pre(csse1001,[]).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not give an example query for `checkSem/2` but I guess that its first argument `Prior` is a list of courses. Then I think you should check if the name of the course is a member in `Prior` and not `pre(Crs, List)`. Second, as you have a list of prerequisites and not just one, you should check that all of them are members in Prior.

```
checkSem(_,[]).
checkSem(Prior,[Crs|Tail]):-
    pre(Crs, List),
    \+ (member(Prereq, List), \+ member(Prereq, Prior)),
    checkSem(Prior,Tail).
```

This goal `\+ (member(Prereq, List), \+ member(Prereq, Prior))` is satisfied if there exists no course `Prereq` that is a member of `List` and it's not a member of `Prior`.

Comment: Yes you're correct, Prior is a list of courses. Oh i see, I was checking if the list was a member of Prior, not an individual item? That makes a lot of sense. Thank you, that's working perfectly :)